# How to install php7.2 in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: php7

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04. When I tried to install some package it asked me to remove many packages by autoremove. So I run the command and it removed the php7.2-fpm.

Now I am unable to install php7.2-fpm.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.2-fpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I tried to add ondrej PPA. But still it is not working.

Please help.

My netbeans also stopped working.

UPDATE

I am now able to use netbeans by installing JDK13. 
I am still forced to use PHP7.3. I am not able to use PHP7.2. Someone asked me to show output of sudo apt-get update. So I am posting it here:

```
xxx@Ubuntu-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan InRelease                
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease               
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:7 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease           
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: please show `sudo apt update` by eding your question.

Comment: There seems to be no package called `php7.2-fpm`. `apt policy` will not find it. There is, however, a package `php-fpm` in the `eoan` repositories. Perhaps installing that will work?

Comment: It will install php7.3. But I need 7.2

Answer (score 9):

You should use the replacement python package to be able to register ondrej's PPA

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

[Installing the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpHj5.png)

Then register the PPA

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Now you can install your PHP packages

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-fpm php7.2-cli php7.2-xml php7.2-mysql
```

Check your available versions

```
update-alternatives --list php
```

And switch to it

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

[Everything is working now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaPV7.png)

Comment: It worked! I don't know how and why it worked. I was also using ondrej repository earlier. But it was not showing any PHP7.2 packages. But today it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @FutureKing i follow same this,but not working from my side getting same errors as your questions "E: Package 'php7.2-fpm' has no installation candidate"

Comment: This is very strange. I will again try in virtual machine

Comment: im having same problem with ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

**Then register the PPA**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

**must install additional repository based on websever**
**for nginx**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
```

**for apache2**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

**install your PHP packages**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-fpm php7.2-cli php7.2-xml php7.2-mysql
```

**Check available versions**

```
update-alternatives --list php
```

**switch to php7.2**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```